# Is there a any way to get the text value of the TextInput using ref in react native?

Tags: react-native, textinput

I am getting the text of the TextInput using onChangeText event and state.

```
      <View style={styles.inputContainerStyle}>
        <TextInput
          autoFoucs={true}
          ref={inputRef}
          style={styles.textInputStyle}
          placeholder="type here ..."
          placeholderTextColor='#838389'
          multiline
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          onChangeText={text => handleTextChange(text)}
          value={selectedText}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.submitBtnWrapperStyle} onPress={() => handleMsgSend()}>
          <Icon name={msgEditMode ? "check" : "paper-plane"} size={20} color="#ffffff" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
```

...

```
// handle text change on textinput
  const handleTextChange = text => {
    channel && channel.typing();
    setSelectedText(text);
  }
```

But actually whenever text is changed, the render function also is called because of changing state value and it is making the whole screen more slow.

So I am looking for the alternative way to get the text not using `onChangeText` event.

Is there any native way to get the text using ref?

I hope kind help.

thanks...

Comment: So are you planning to get the value from the textinput when you press a button from the parent ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access the value of text input using ref like this

```
this.inputRef._lastNativeText
```